# How do different ways of interpolating complex numbers affect the discrete Fourier transform?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

I have an array of 1000 complex numbers $\vec b$. Here is an example of the norms of the numbers in $\vec b$: [image: norms of b[1]]

Taking the fast Fourier transform of $\vec b$, then the norm, gives the frequency space spectrum: [image: frequency space spectrum]

I want to increase the range of this spectrum. Since I do not have more time domain data, I want to interpolate the values in $\vec b$. Obviously, the high frequency information will depend on the method of interpolation. Here is the previous frequency spectrum with double the amounts of points in $\vec b$, linearly interpolated:

[image: interpolated frequency spectrum]

Changing linear interpolation to spline, the frequency spectrum keeps about the same shape in the low frequencies (~800-1200) but changes slightly outside of that range, as expected. By assuming that the phase changes slowly between points, I used another interpolation scheme: $z_{interp} = e^{i\phi_{interp}}(|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2)/2$ where $\phi_{interp} = (arg(z_1)+arg(z_2))/2$, and this is the frequency spectrum that came out

[image: phase_interp]

I do not understand how this is possible as the low frequencies should not have been affected so drastically. Obviously there is something I do not understand about the relationship between interpolation and Fourier transforms.

Comment: Your interpolation is not continuous because arg isn't! Also, your $|z_{interp}|$ is can be *much* greater than $|z_{1,2}|$. - I thnk for the kind of interpolation you wanted to try, you want to take something like $\sqrt{|z_1z_2|}\frac{z_1+z_2}{|z_1+z_2|}$

Comment: Ah, so discontinuous interpolation is meaningless?